# Can you define a string in a theme sheet to be used as an x:key value?

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm playing around with themes, and see you can define a whole bunch of things derived from objects, or associated to types of classes... SolidBrushColor, Button, TextBox, etc.

You can then apply x:Key="something" and then later have it bound into a style, such as

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SomeSolidBrushColor}" />
```

So, my question is this.  Can you do the same, but with a "string" that you want to use constantly... example a font name to be explicitly used on all controls... Button, Label, TextBox, CheckBox, etc.  So you could have a string with a value of "Arial", "Tahoma", "Wingdings", then within each of the styles for the actual controls you could do something like

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MyCommonFontName}" />
```

Likewise the value could represent a string to be used for things like common margins, borders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a string resource for the font because it is a string and not a FontFamily object :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <media:FontFamily x:Key="Font">Stencil</media:FontFamily>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Font}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button>hello</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, but couldn't figure the origin of the type to be used.  media did it...

Comment: Can you do the similar with a solidBrushColor... have a master color and derive from that in exact same fashion?